# Calculating period/SMA delta and other parameters from Clohessy-Wiltshire

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics

I'm working on the camera system for a game about relative motion.  The orbital motion is completely described by Clohessy-Wiltshire.

I would like to be able to calculate some things like eccentricity of the chaser, and the period/SMA delta between chaser and target.  Is there a method to do this that doesn't involve creating a "base" elset that matches the orbital rate being used for CW and a chaser elset based on the CW pos/vel?

Comment: vanilla CW assumes the target object is in a circular orbit around a point mass.  if you want to chase anything more complicated than that, you need to add in lots more terms that are usually assumed zero, and then solve those new equations, as in Sparrow & Price 1968 ( https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/80665728.pdf )

Comment: Correct, and my target meets those requirements by definition. I would like to calculate the current eccentricity of the chaser, which is not required to be circular.

Comment: okay, then i'm sorry, i can't help, because what you describe is all i've done with them before.